# Why does writing to a deleted file not return an error in Go?

Tags: file, go

This program successfully runs even though it's writing to a deleted file. Why does this work?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    const path = "test.txt"

    f, err := os.Create(path) // Create file
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = os.Remove(path) // Delete file
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = f.WriteString("test") // Write to deleted file
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Printf("No errors occurred") // test.txt doesn't exist anymore
}
```

Comment: you still have a file descriptor to it

Comment: If this is on linux, you can delete an open file, and continue reading from/writing to it. The file will be actually deleted when all handles referring to it are closed. This is actually used with temp files: program creates the file and deletes it immediately, but keeps writing to it. When the program terminates, the file is gone. I'm not sure if windows allows a process to delete its own open files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Unix-like systems, when a process opens a file it gets a [`File descriptor`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor#cite_note-bach-3) which points to the process `File table` entry, which, in turn, refers to [inode structure](https://linoxide.com/linux-command/linux-inode) on the disk. `inode` keeps file information, including `data location`.

Contents of a directory are just pairs of inode numbers and names.

If you delete a file, you simply delete a link to `inode` from the directory, `inode` still exists (as long as there is no link to it from somewhere, including processes) and data can be read and written from/to `data location`.

On Windows this code fails since Windows does not allow opened file to be deleted:

```
panic: remove test.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
D:/tmp/main.go:18 +0x1d1
exit status 2
```